# NUMBER FIELD Item Type - Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

All of my number fields aren't working in Oracle APEX 23.

When I fill out my item and submit the page, the item just returns zero:

[Before:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLUsR.png)

[After:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWvfv.png)

This only occurs with the number field; text fields work perfectly.

Every page/item that has the number field isn't functioning.

Is there any way to see/change how the number field is created in the Oracle APEX engine?

Thanks a lot!!!

I tried everything, but nothing work's.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to try to reproduce your issue.

1. Create a new page with an empty region.
2. Add the following components

- Page Item: P174_ITEM_NUMBER (type Number Field)
- Page Item: P174_ITEM_TEXT (type Text Field)
- Button (action: Submit Page)

3. Create a pl/sql process in the "Processing" section with code

```
apex_debug.info(
    p_message => q'#kl debug: P174_ITEM_NUMBER: %0#',
    p0        => :P174_ITEM_NUMBER);
apex_debug.info(
    p_message => q'#kl debug: P174_ITEM_TEXT: %0#',
    p0        => :P174_ITEM_TEXT);
```

4. Run the page, enter value in 2 page items
5. Submit page

Observe

1. the items both have values.
2. In debug, the values are being captured:

[image]

So, in this simple case, Number fields and Text fields are behaving exactly the same. Something must be different in your case.